# Track my costs on azure (FrontEnd-Pool, UnusedPool)

Tags: azure

Im an azure newbe.

A while ago, I tested out some azure  functionality. An app-service to test out azure functions  and a webapp.

My (only) resource group is named MyRG (red line in attached picture). 
A few weeks after I get the message that all my MSDN Pro-free-quota is used up. I can see that 99.9 of the resources was eaten up by 
"FrontEnd_Pool_for_MyRG-appservice" and "Unused_Pool_for_MyRG-appservice"

[image: Overview of costs]

When I look at my overview (below)

[image: Overview of my azure account]

**So... to my question: 
can I find my costs in the overview, so I can remove/deactivate it?** I cant test anything right until tomorrow, since its all deactivated

Bonus question)

Im using this as personal dev area.
What is the easiest way to deactivate a resource when Im not using it, I guess my mistake here was that I didnt deactivate something (expensive). Can I automate deactivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is the correct answer, in case I forget to log in here in 2 days and mark it)

Created an azure serivice ticket which went surprisingly smooth and fast.
Two calls and I got the answer. Sorry MS if I trashed your customer service, this time it was great :)

Everytime you create an "app service" (second row on my second screenshot), youll get the FrontEnd_Pool/Unused_Pool. I didnt use mine, so I removed it, and the problem should go away.

Thanks Feranto! Your help lead me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

**So for the first question**. Yes you can, to do this you should follow the next steps:

- Go to the [[image]azure](/questions/tagged/azure) portal
- Look for the subscription option

[image]

- Select your subscription
- There you can see an overview
- Then you can click the graph that says "Costs by resource"
- Here you will get a complete detail of your costs by the name of component, what type of component it is and finally to what resource group it belongs

[image]

Here you will be able to see every component by its original name, type or resource group name. Hope this works out for you!

And for the **bonus question**, if you are using `PAAS` services in [[image]azure](/questions/tagged/azure) it is not enough just to stop the service as it is in `IAAS` with vms. The only way to stop an app service from charging you is either deleting it or updating the App plan service to the Free tier. I would recommend the second one.

This is in the first faq in [Microsoft's App Service website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/#). :

> Am I charged for apps while they are in stopped state?
>
> Yes. Rates listed apply to apps in stopped state. Please delete apps
>   that are not in use or update tier to Free to avoid charges.

You can automate this process(either deleting or updating app service plan) trough the use of Azure Clients like the REST API, azure-cli or powershell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Feranto! Regarding the answer to my first question, my first screen shot is from subscriptions->/my msdn pro subscription/->overview, so I did find the costs, just want to know what service I can deactivate (or rather delete, acc to your second answer). Your second answer was really helpful info, but my main issue is how do I know *what* in the "azure overview" to delete/change to free tier. Nothing there says "FrontEnd_Pool" or "Unused_Pool", so I guess its a part of something else. My first guess was my "My-RG-webapp", but that is specifically specified as 0 cost

Comment: hey @Cowborg, I understand your question. Of course we cannot tell you what services to activate or deactivate, nor explain the values that appear per service. But I have update the answer for you to be able to reach the "Costs by service" blade, which can give you a full estimates on everything based on the name of the service, the type and the resource group. If my answer is helpful please don't forget to upvote it, or mark it as the answer.

Comment: Ive looked at your updated answer, but my first screen shot is taken from that exact view (lower right part of your second screen shot is same as my first screen shot). As you can see there 99.9% is taken up by the two items "FrontEnd_Pool" or "Unused_Pool", but neither of those is anything I recognize from anything Ive ordered/set up/named or have in my overview, so I guess that they, for example was a part of every webapp you setup (in that case I would have removed my web app), I just know that I need to remove them from my subscription. Again, thanks for taking the time

Comment: @Cowborg, it is not possible for us to answer why those values appear in your subscription. We can help you to show you where you can see those values and how to disable them. But then, if you have suspicious about the values, then you should send a support ticket to Azure to have them explain the "why" of those values. Have a nice day! Don't forget to upvote or mark as an answer ;).

Comment: I thought I ask here first, Ill wait to see if anyone else knows about these, since MS customer service is a Kafka-like nightmare (Ive been there). It doesnt seem to be anything "suspicious", other that the confusing way that MS specify the costs. I did upvote you, but since I have <15 in rep it will not show here. I cant mark it as an answer though, since I still dont know what resource that I need to turn off/disable.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'll flag your question, since it has become unclear and ambiguous, which is not possible to answer.